# Selenium server does not open browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat

I'm trying to get our tried and tested Behat setup to work, but even though Selenium server is up and running, the browser window never opens when I run my script. It seems to be running headless (which it's not supposed to do) but when I check my output file then none of the steps have passed.

I've tried deleting everything and starting from scratch with a fresh pull, but nothing does the trick. Unfortunately I have no idea how I'm supposed to troubleshoot this particular problem so it seems like you guys are my last hope.

I'm guessing my setup would not be of much value since it's already working across multiple other machines but maybe someone has experienced a similar problem and might have a suggestion as to what the error might be. If you need anymore information then please let me know and I'll be happy to provide it.

**I use the following when I start Selenium Server:**

selenium-server-standalone-2.9.0.jar

chromedriver-2.24

InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit) 2.53.1.0

**Powershell script that I use to start Selenium Server:**

```
Param (
      [string] $FireFoxBinary  
      )
$SeleniumServerPath = (Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition) 
if (-not ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($FireFoxBinary))) {
    $WebDriverFireFoxBin ="""-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=$FireFoxBinary"""
}
java -jar (Join-Path $SeleniumServerPath "selenium-server-standalone-2.9.0.jar")  "-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=$(Join-Path $SeleniumServerPath IEDriverServer.exe)" "-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=$(Join-Path $SeleniumServerPath chromedriver-2.24.exe)" $WebDriverFireFoxBin
```

**Console output when starting Selenium server:**

> INFO: Launching a standalone server
>   Setting system property webdriver.ie.driver to D:\Data\git_stuff\ebiz-test-automation\Framework\Selenium_server\selenium_2.9.0\IEDriverServer.exe
>   Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to D:\Data\git_stuff\ebiz-test-automation\Framework\Selenium_server\selenium_2.9.0\chromedriver-2.24.exe
>   14:16:09.054 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.121-b13
>   14:16:09.070 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
>   14:16:09.070 INFO - v2.9.0, with Core v2.9.0. Built from revision 14289
>   14:16:09.210 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
>   14:16:09.210 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
>   14:16:09.210 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>   14:16:09.382 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@7d4793a8
>   14:16:09.382 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
>   14:16:09.382 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
>   14:16:09.382 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
>   14:16:09.398 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
>   14:16:09.398 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@5b6f7412

Comment: please show how you are instantiating the webdriver in your code, and any console output that is displayed.  also provide which versions of selenium, the browser, and operating system you are running.  Your original question is verbose but contains absolutely no information that can be used to help you.

Comment: You should add at least something, some error, profile from behat.yml. If absolute everything in the setup is the same then the selenium server might be the issue, maybe different driver or different browser version.

Comment: I've updated my original post with some more information about my setup. Unfortunately I don't get an error, so I can't post any information regarding that. If you need even more information then I'll update as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that helps a lot of people who've encountered your sort of problem is maximizing the browser.  Even a headless browser needs room to render.  I just use:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

You should also try to take a screenshot immediately after the first driver.get().

Answer (score 0):

Not a very good setup for starting **selenium server** in my opinion.

You should keep in mind that with browser update the old selenium might not work as expected.

If you want to keep the same structure you should also add the path to the new selenium server.

Try running with firefox, get the latest selenium server 3.1.0 and the latest chromedriver 2.27 and start selenium without the script to test it.

Download both (driver+selenium) in the same directory, open a console and run something like this,

for windows:
`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.1.0.jar`

for mac:
`java -Dwebdrive.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.1.0.jar`

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking a question with an obvious answer but why is this not a very good setup for starting Selenium server? I would love to change the setup if something makes more sense than what we have, but I'm not sure where the problem lies.